# SQL retrieve rows based on column condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery, where-clause

Say I have below tables

Order Table

```
OrderNo  CategoryID  CountryID  ServiceTypeID
 100         1         3             1
 200         2         5             2
 300         3         4             4
 400         1         2             9
```

1 service Type might belong to many category type

Category Table

```
 ID   Name  ServiceTypeID
 1     x        1
 2     x        2
 3     x        1
```

ServiceType table

```
 ID    Name
 1     xx
 2     xx
 3     xx
```

Tracking Table

```
OrderNo  CountryID   TrackingTypeID
 100        2             3
 200        1             4
 100        3             2
 400        5             1
 200        2             6
```

Reviewd Table

```
OrderNo 
 300
 100
 200
```

I want to write a query with below requirements

Order must belong to serviceTypeID = 1 or 2

And If the orderNo has a categoryID = 1

I want that record to be retrieved only if
there's a record in tracking table for that
orderNo with same countryID as in Order table

and if that orderNo doesn't have tracking type of id (0,7,1) in tracking table

Else for all other orders with any other category excluding orders which are not belong
to serviceTypeID = (1,2)
I want that record to be retrived only if
there's an existing record for that orderNo in
Reviewed table

and if that orderNo doesn't have tracking type of id (0,7,1) in tracking table

So basically based on above requirements the result should look like

```
OrderNo   CategoryID  StationID   
 100         1           3          
 200         2           5



select DISTINCT top 10000  o.orderNo , o.categoryID , o.serviceTypeid 
,o.countrtId , Tracking.countryId
from Order o
join Tracking on o.orderNo = Tracking.orderNo 

where

(o.CategoryID in (1 ) and o.countryId = Tracking.countryId 
       and
       exists (select 1
               from tracking t
               where t.orderNo = o.orderNo and t.countryId  = 
               o.countryId 
              )
      )

  OR
  (o.categoryID  in (select id from Category where ServiceTypeid in (7,8) and 
    ID not in (56 , 65)
    ) and
    exists (select 1
           from Reviewed r
           where r.orderNo = o.orderNo 
          )
  ) 

 AND not exists
                ( select 1
                 from tracking t
                 WHERE T.orderNo = o.orderNo 
                 and t.TrackingTypeID in (0 , 7 ,25))
```

That query seems to return only orders with ID 1 and even if it's have a trackingTypeID = 0,7,25

Comment: Please don't insert EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best presentation as of right now. [help] But don't edit in a way that invalidates reasonable posted answers.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `exists` and boolean logic:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where 
    (
        category_id = 1 
        and exists (select 1 from tracking t where t.order_no = o.order_no and t.country_id = o.country_id)
    )
    or (
        category_id = 2
        and exists (select 1 from reviewed r where r.order_no = o.order_no)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your conditions, you can use boolean logic with `exists`:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where (o.categoryid = 1 and
       exists (select 1
               from tracking t
               where t.orderno = o.orderno and t.CountryID = o.CountryID
              )
      ) or
      (o.categoryid = 2 and
       exists (select 1
               from reviewed r
               where r.orderno = o.orderno 
              )
      ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your conditions this query will give results accordingly:

```
Select o.OrderNo,o.CategoryID,o.CountryID as StationID
    from Order o
    inner join Tracking t on t.OrderNo = o.OrderNo and t.CountryID = o.CountryID
    where o.CategoryID = 1 or (o.CategoryID = 2 
    and exists (Select * from Reviewed where OrderNo = o.OrderNo))
```